# Why can't I update Tensorflow via pip from version 2.0 to 2.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, upgrade

When I enter the command to update tensorflow pip starts downloading the necessary files. The download is then aborted and the font color in the dos window changes to yellow. What is going on?

[image: python]

Comment: Did you try uninstalling version 2.0 instead of attempting the upgrade? There seem to be some issues with TF 2.1 and older versions installed, so upgrade might not work

Comment: Are you able to download the `whl` manually and then install?

Comment: @GPhilo reinstallation after uninstallation failed

Comment: With the same behaviour or did anything change?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Unfortunately the installation via reference to the manually downloaded whl file does not work either

Comment: @GPhilo Same behaviour. Strangely enough I could not update pip either. After restarting the console, and activation of the virtual environment the installation of tensorflow could be performed and pip could be upgraded as well

Comment: Try running `pip install tensorflow --upgrade -vvv`, maybe the verbose output has more info.

Comment: @hoefling problem is solved already and i am not able to reproduce it right know. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: This might cause problems if the OP doesn't first uninstall the old one

Comment: `pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow` resulted in the same behaviour